# Using proxy in Telegram messenger

Tags: encryption, proxy, privacy, telegram-messenger

In `Telegram` messenger, there is an option to set connection type. I can set my proxy setting and use Telegram with the proxy. I would like to know if I use the proxy, are my data and privacy forwarded to the proxy server given that `Telegram` uses end to end encryption? In fact, I want to know the third party (proxy server) can read my all personal data which I send in `Telegram`?

Comment: Yes, by using a proxy the “end to end” encryption is between the proxy and Telegram.  Your connection to the proxy can be encrypted, if it’s encrypted, depends on your setup.  However, just because the “end to end” encryption is between the proxy and another client doesn’t mean the data can be read by the proxy.  This is due to how Telegram works.  Read their advanced FAQ for more information

Comment: I am confused, if the proxy is able to read my personal data, why Telegram set this feature in its app? @Ramhound

Comment: To get around situations where it isn’t possible to connect to their service unless you use a proxy.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct because Telegram is based on privacy. In situations where it isn’t possible to connect to their service, you can set the proxy setting in your network connection and use Telegram, and there is no need to set this feature in the Telegram application due to privacy. So, I still want to know why they set this feature. @Ramhound

Comment: The use of a proxy doesn’t increase or decrease the security of Telegram, I never said it did, my wording was specific.  I also didn’t submit an answer, what I have submitted it a comment, I did that intentionally

Comment: I mean Telegram pays attention to privacy very much, so if your point of view is correct, why Telegram set this feature which is in contradiction with privacy? @Ramhound

Comment: "why Telegram set this feature which is in contradiction with privacy?" -  Read my previous comment.  There isn't a contradiction with privacy.  You are buying into Telegram's marketing.  You shouldn't do that.

Comment: I don't understand what you say or you don't understand what I say. @Ramhound

Answer (score 2):

Telegram added the ability to add a proxy in their [4.1 update](https://telegram.org/blog/admin-revolution) to help circumvent censorship by service providers or governments (or any other entity who is responsible for your network access for that matter).

*You don't really need to use Telegram with a proxy if you can use Telegram without it, or if you don't care that your ISP or network provider knows that you are connecting to Telegram servers.*

By setting up a proxy server the traffic will be routed via the proxy server, which means that the proxy server is able to see the raw communication between your app and the Telegram servers.

This, however, does **not** mean that the proxy can access your private information or personal data. Telegram's communication is protected by their [MTProto protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto), which is controversial due to their unconventional use of different techniques, but to public knowledge not broken.

In their FAQ they also mention this:

> Telegram can help when it comes to data transfer and secure
>   communication. This means that all data (including media and files)
>   that you send and receive via Telegram cannot be deciphered when
>   intercepted by your ISP, network administrator or other third parties.

https://telegram.org/faq#q-can-telegram-protect-me-against-everything

Comment: Therefore you say that first, my messages are encrypted and then, they are sent to the proxy server? So proxy cannot decipher it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I think this just happens in the `secret chat` mode in Telegram according to the FAQ. But in the desktop application, Telegram doesn't support this feature.

Comment: They do. Telegram Messaging is encrypted regardless of the type of chat. Just the encryption changes depending on what kind of chat you chose.
Secret Chats are end-to-end encrypted. Only one of your devices and one of your chat partners devices have the encryption keys. Normal (cloud) chats have a server to client encryption.

I would recommend reaching out to their support by selecting "Ask a question" in your Telegram app's settings, if you want them to confirm this.

Comment: @Patris Desktop apps use HTTPS via proxy, therefore the connection is encrypted, eliminating the need to encrypt messages themselves while in transit.